# Facebook Connect - Switched from JavaScript Authentication to OAuth - Re-Authorization?

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-graph-api, authorization, facebook-c#-sdk

In **version 1** of my website, i implemented Facebook Connect with the JavaScript API. This included authentication, permissions, and publishing.

In **version 2** of my website (what i'm implementing now), i have implemented Facebook Connect with the Graph API (OAuth).

I haven't touched the Facebook settings in my application. But when i attempted to authenticate using OAuth, it asked for the same permissions again (email, basic information) - even though i had already granted those before (using version 1)

The only difference i can see if that previously i asked for permissions via `FB.showPermissionsDialog`, now i use the `scope` parameter in the login page URL (OAuth).

What this means is when i go live, all my users will have to re-authorize my app, when they in fact shouldn't.

Any ideas? Is it because i'm now using AppId/Secret (OAuth) instead of ApiKey/Secret (JS API)?

FYI i'm using the Facebook Connect C# Toolkit.

Comment: What is the "Facebook Connect C# Toolkit"?  Do you mean the Facebook C# SDK (which is how you tagged your question?)

Comment: @Pat James - yes, my bad - Facebook C# SDK

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem goes on unsolved, but site is live so not much i can do about it now.

Not a huge deal anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that makes sense. Are you using the same application id? The permissions are between the application and the user, as far as I know.

Comment: Yep, that's what i thought too. It's the same App Id. But's its OAuth now, instead of the javascript dialog. I think that's the problem. Facebook shouldn't care though - but they obviously do.

Comment: Why don't you post the JS code and the oAuth click URL you are using.

Comment: It's pretty simple. The OAuth URL is whatever is generated by the Facebook C# Toolkit, and the JS code is FB.init (basic JS api stuff)

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to validate your oauth using javascript-sdk:

[Check this response hope this gives you some idea.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690723/facebook-graph-api-and-django/5539531#5539531)